# Eclipse RCP features install but no plugins show up when i restart eclipse after the installation

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle, update-site

I wrote some plugins for an existing Eclipse/Equinox RCP Application. Previously i was able to install them just fine by using an update site.

After the RCP Application updated this is not possible anymore (`org.osgi.framework.version` from `1.5.0` to `1.6.0`, `osgi.framework.version` from `3.6.1.R36x_v20100806` to `3.7.2.v20120110-1415`):

- The features are installed (listed in `features/`, show up in `Help->Software Updates->Manage Configuration`).
- The Feature-Status shows `No plug-in: "XY" included at runtime.` for all plugins in the feature.
- The `plugins/` folder contains the `.jar` files
- When i use `ss` on the OSGI console the bundles are not shown.
- The exact same update site works fine in the old version of the RCP Application
- When i install the same plugins from the OSGI console with the `install` command the plugins work fine. (Fresh version of the RCP Application/Using the same jars that were in the Update site)

What can i do to diagnose or solve this problem?

EDIT: **If i press the `Apply Changes` Button instead of the `Yes->Restart` Button after installing the features they get installed properly**...

Comment: Possibly any 'bundle-version' values in the 'Require-Bundle' in the plugin MANIFEST.MF does not match the new versions.

Comment: so the osgi console ignores the MANIFEST.MF Require-Bundle?